# Sorting array of 1000 distinct integers in the range [1, 5000], accessing each element at most once

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Suppose you have an array of 1000 integers. The integers are in random order, but you know each of the integers is between 1 and 5000 (inclusive). In addition, 
each number appears only once in the array. Assume that you can access each element of the array only once. Describe an algorithm to sort it.

**How i can sorting?**

**If you used auxiliary storage in your algorithm, can you find an algorithm that remains O(n) space complexity?**

Comment: Your question is *extremely* unclear. There's no way of answering it at the moment. I suggest you clarify it, or it'll be closed really quickly.

Answer (score 2):

```
        int[] firstarray = ....; // input array
        bool[] counterList = new bool[5000];

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            counterList[firstarray[i]] = true;
        }

        int nCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {
            if (counterList[i])
                firstarray[nCount++] = i;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a [count sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort), which will be O(5000) time and space complexity, which is pretty much O(N). This is a fairly good match for your ratio of 1000 numbers : range of 5000. Hopefully this meets your requirement of reading each number only once, even though it kind of "stores" them in the buckets.

If you want to save some memory, and likely some time (at most a constant factor of 5), then you can use larger buckets. Take a look at [bucket sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort).